# filter matrix based on table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have these two RELATED (on cCode) tables

Companies:

| cCode | Company | HQ Address | other details... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Coca Cola | Georgia | blah blah |
| 2 | Pepsico | New York | yadda yadda |

Products:

| Product | cCode | Calories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Coke | 1 | 100 |
| Diet Coke | 1 | 0 |
| Coke Zero | 1 | 0 |
| more Coke... | 1 | various |
| Pepsi | 2 | 100 |
| Diet Pepsi | 2 | 0 |
| more Pepsi... | 2 | various |

In my report, I have a *table* listing all Products.  I also have a *matrix* showing each Company and all of their Products.  If a user selects a Product from the *table*, I want the *matrix* to show all of the Products belonging to the same company; otherwise, show all Companies and Products.  Nothing selected gives this *matrix*:

| Company | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Coke | Coke |
|  | Diet Coke |
|  | Coke Zero |
|  | more Coke... |
| Pepsi | Pepsi |
|  | Diet Pepsi |
|  | more Pepsi... |

Selecting Diet Coke from the *table* gives this *matrix*:

| Company | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Coke | Coke |
|  | Diet Coke |
|  | Coke Zero |
|  | more Coke... |

I created a measure like this:

```
includeFlag = 
  VAR selectedCode = SELECTEDVALUE(Companies[cCode])
  VAR flag = IF(ISBLANK(selectedCode), 1, IF(MIN(Products[cCode]) = selectedCode, 1, 0))
RETURN flag
```

and added it as a filter to *matrix* (show when includeFlag = 1).  It's only showing me the single product I selected.  How do I get it to show all products for the same company?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your current DAX measure is checking the selected value from the `Companies` table, but in your scenario, the user is selecting a product from the `Products` table. The `selectedCode` variable is not correctly capturing the company code of the selected product.

```
includeFlag = 
VAR selectedProductCode = SELECTEDVALUE(Products[cCode])
VAR currentProductCode = MIN(Products[cCode])

RETURN
IF(
    ISBLANK(selectedProductCode), 
    1, 
    IF(currentProductCode = selectedProductCode, 1, 0)
)
```

So if there's no product selected, show everything (`includeFlag = 1` for all) and if a product is selected, you will check if the current product in the context of the matrix belongs to the same company as the selected product. If it does, return 1 (to include it) otherwise 0.

Comment: Thanks @amira-bedhiafi, though this didn't work for me.  I set VAR a = SELECTEDVALUE(Products[cCode]), VAR b = SELECTEDVALUE(Companies[cCode]), VAR c = MIN(Products[cCode]), VAR d = MIN(Companies[cCode]) then have includeFlag return a-b-c-d.  What it outputs is " - cCode - - cCode" except for the product selected which gives "cCode - cCode - cCode - cCode" so I'm still seeing only the product I select and not all products for the same company.  For some reason, it's not picking up the Products[cCode].  Can you help?

Comment: Can you please share your file ?

Comment: Unfortunately not since it has proprietary data :(